# Android app button

Tags: android, button, accelerometer

I want to create a button that showing out an emoji with using an accelerometer in mobile phone. I think I have to hold the button to record the value from accelerometer. If I release the button, the function will be stopped. I have searched some similar codes but I didn't got one that contains the button style. I don't want two buttons for start and cancel.

Comment: Button style? What is your actual question? The click event, the accelerometer, show an emoji? Please ask what you want specifically, not the whole function of your app

Comment: What's your question ?

Comment: I have created a function that show an emoji if I shaking. But I want to use a button to start running my function and stop running if I release the button like audio recording button in Whatsapp

Comment: If I understand your question, you probably want a SimpleGestureDetector.  Start with `onDown` & end with `onSingleTapUp`.  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener.html   https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html